# Javascript multidimensional array undefined error

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm having some trouble creating a multidimensional array where im putting some counties and places that are in the county.

Example of what im trying to do:

```
[
    'HEDMARK' => [
        1 => 'ELVERUM',
        2 => 'HAMAR 
    ],
    'OSLO' => [
        1 => 'OSLO'
    ]
]
```

The code im using is this:

```
    var $query_place = [];

    // Get each checked county
    $.each($('.county input:checkbox:checked'), function () {
        $query_place.push({
            county: $(this).val(),
            postal: []
        });
    });

    // Get each checked postal
    $.each($('.postal input:checkbox:checked'), function() {
        $query_place[$(this).attr('data-county')].postal.push();
    });
```

The error im getting in the console is this:

```
TypeError: $query_place[$(...).attr(...)] is undefined
```

Is there something im forgetting here? Or have i just done this wrong?

[image: the checkboxes]

Comment: Do you specifically need an array of objects? A single object would seem to be a much more simple and effective solution here.

Comment: Use `$().data( attributeName )` better, and mind the `county`typo perhaps ^^

Comment: Look in your browser dev tool (firebug in firefox for instance) to see what you really have in your array, it could help.

Comment: Yea, I need an array of objects. So that each county, gets its own array of postals. Tried using `$().data` instead, but I get the same error.

I tried to switch the the inside of `$.each` postal line to `alert($(this).val());` but it doesn't alert anything, so i think i can't use $(this) for some reason.

Comment: I know got each county to work right (http://imgur.com/wlZYu5p). I only need know to get each postal pushed in to the array where it belongs. How would i do that? I tried the following, but it gives me an error (TypeError: $query_place.county is undefined)
`$query_place.county[$(this).attr('data-county')].postal.push($(this).val());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implement your code like this

```
var $query_place = [];    
    // Get each checked county
    $.each($('input:checkbox.county:checked'), function () {
        $query_place.push({
            county: $(this).val(),
            postal: setPostal($(this).val())
        });        
    });           

    function setPostal(county)
    {
        var postal = [];
        // Get each checked postal
        $.each($('input:checkbox.postal:checked'), function () {
            if ($(this).attr('data-county') == county)
                postal.push($(this).val());
        });
        return postal;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to parse the `$query_place` array object before pushing any values into it.

```
$.each($('.county input:checkbox:checked'), function () {
var values={};
values.county= $(this).val();
values.postal=[];
var a=JSON.parse($query_place);
a.push(value);

})
```